# BeautifulSoup and find

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a html code:

```
<div id='div1'>
    <div id='d'> </div>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

How do I get all that in a div with an id div1?
soup.find('div',{'id':"div1"})  returns:

```
<div id='div1'>
    <div id='d'> </div>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

I need to get only:

```
<div id='d'> </div>
<p></p>
```

Comment: "soup.find('div',{'id':"div1"}) returns data with div1." What shall that mean? It returns exactly the matched node. What else do you want?

Comment: Read documentation please and check the renderContents() method or the contents attribute.

Answer (score 4):

See the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html), specifically [`.find()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#find%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20%2a%2akwargs%29) and [`.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#contents).

Answer (score 0):

You want the content between the start and end of the tag including all child tags.

`soup.find('div', id="div1").contents`